# Promp user for input. Hit enter to exit

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Say I created a dictionary called color_cat with keys  and values

I was wondering how I can prompt the user for a key input and display the corresponding value of the key entered, but if the return key is hit, then the program ends.

I tried using a variable for the input and an if loop. Say `c` is my variable and if I hit enter then the variable is the return key (can I do that?) but if its anything else then I take that input as the key and print the value of the dictionary.

Any tip is greatly appreciated!

My code looks something like:

```
i = input("input color of cat")  
if i == "" :  
        import sys  
        sys.exit()  
else: 
        print "the cat number is", color_cat['i']
```

Comment: I suppose the single quotes in `color_cat['i']` are a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  a = input("Enter number");
```

If you press press enter without entering anything :

```
  a = ''
```

So you can check using a if condition if your variable equals the above returned value.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing enter returns nothing, so check if the input is

```
""
```

And if it is, exit.